# How to migrate data from Mongo db to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

We want to migrate huge volume of data assume 20 million from Mongo DB to Firestore.

I know we can do this through programmatically but is there any tool out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know we can do this through programmatically but is there any tool out there?

The answer is no! If you're looking for a magic button that can convert your `MongoDB` database to `Cloud Firestore`, you need to know that there isn't one! So unfortunately, you'll need to convert your database yourself, even if it holds 20 million records. The best way to achieve that, is to design your database schema according to Firestore requirements using collections and documents and copy all of your data in smaller chunks.

Comment: Thank Alex for your answer.

Comment: yep i already accepted your answer

Comment: For those looking how to do it, here is a good article: https://medium.com/@dev.prasenjitsaha/migrate-mongodb-data-to-cloud-firestore-79a68ee18aa3